# I deleted dllhost.exe. How can I get it back?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, task-manager

I was curious about COM Surrogate in my task manager. I looked up the file, I saw and saw the word virus repeated multiple times which caused me to quickly permanently remove dllhost.exe from my PC. Now, I discovered that the file was actually made by Microsoft and now my PC is acting funny.

How can I get the file back without downloading it from a trojan website? Does Microsoft have an official download for dllhost.exe?

Comment: @Adam5 - System restore is your best option since you deleted a required system file.  **In the future don't delete system files**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Command Prompt as an administrator and type:

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

After it's done:

sfc /scannow

Comment: Cleanup-image freezes at 20%. This PC is old and has been hanging by a thread for a while now.

Comment: I'll suggest you to try this aproach first:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dismexe-online-cleanup-image-restore-health-failed/668ef107-5f4c-4959-ba93-76d052452315?messageId=ee50ba1a-9922-47c6-ad44-ac3de74c5844&page=4

If it doesn't work try this:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/dism-online-cleanup-image-checkhealth-stops-20/d867da9a-8c7b-4846-a041-7a4b889c833b

Comment: I skipped the DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth and just did the sfc /scannow part and it worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.